# add user to database in cpanel (Privilage User) using php script

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, privileges

I am trying to add user to my database,but is not work..i have used follwing script,but is not work for me.please find the solution.

```
function addUserToDb($cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$userName,$dbName,$privileges) {

$buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/sql/addusertodb.html?user=".$userName."&db=".$dbName.$privileges;

$openSocket = fsockopen('www.winsolsolutions.in',2082);
if(!$openSocket) {
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
}

$authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
$authPass = base64_encode($authString);
$buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Host:www.winsolsolutions.in\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
}
fclose($openSocket);
}
addUserToDb($cpaneluser,$cpanelpass,$dbusernbame,$dbname,'&ALL=ALL');
```

Comment: Don't use raw sockets, try curl. Also, what means "its not working"? What is the response you get?

Comment: why don't you just click on the mysql section in C-pannel and add the user that way?

Comment: but i want to add this user to database  using php script